# C# program lost assembly reference at execution

Tags: c#, .net

I have problem when first two methods called from assembly work properly, but on third I have couldn't load referenced assembly exception. I have tried to load the assembly like this:

```
Assembly module = Assembly.LoadFile(Path.GetFullPath(path));
Assembly module = Assembly.LoadFile(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
```

And referred hardly by adding into project references. No idea why I have some referenced libraries that persists in app folder and starts to be unavailable at execution.

Windows forms application, if it matters.

Comment: Is the assembly still in the bin folder?

Comment: Yes, already have tried to disable antivirus....

Comment: Never, never, never use LoadFile, always LoadFrom.  LoadFile is only appropriate if you *intentionally* don't want to find dependent assemblies.  That is exceedingly rare.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because your reference is **older, or newer from your current framework**.

if your reference is not running on the same framework, it is highly likely that some method will not load, happened to me with the NLOG reference, I updated it and all problems solved, apparently some of the methods were removed for not supporting the framework - **deprecated**.

Please check the version of the assembly and the version of your .NET framework to see that everything is on a straight line regarding the framework.

This is the main reason for headaches like this.